# Why method mail() does not work?

Tags: php, email

I'm doing a form of registration.

I want that every time that an user is signed up, a mail arrive to me.
So I made this:

```
mail("myemail@hotmail.com", "New User", $message);
```

In `$message` I have the username of new user.

I try to do some test with fake data. I signed up correctly but the mail doesn't arrive. Why?

Edit: now I try to add header:

```
"From: User $uname <noreply@mysite.com>"
```

Edit2: I have print mail and I receive 1! But I don't receive mail! What could be the problem? In junk mail I don't have mail!

Comment: Is your server configured to send out emails? Where are the headers? Do you have error reporting turned on for your code? Are you getting any error messages ?

Comment: check your spam; Hotmail hates it when people use `mail()` with malformed headers.

Comment: how can I see an error message?

Comment: `if(mail("myemail@hotmail.com", "New User", $message)){ echo "Sent, it's out of your hands now.";} else{ echo "Check your spam, or if you haven't been blacklisted.";}`

Comment: *"how can I see an error message?"* Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.